# Use SSH Public Key Login for Deja Dup

Tags: ssh, backup, deja-dup

I have an encrypted hard drive mounted on a Raspberry Pi that I am using for backups on the local network. I have public key authentication set up for the Pi, so I can log in via SSH without a password. After using the SSH address for the backup location, Deja Dup asks for a login to the Pi when it runs the backup.

Is there a way to use Deja Dup with a public key login? If not, how secure is saving the password?

Comment: When you configure Deja Dup to use SSH, it seems that it actually uses an SFTP backend, not SSH. This may be related to your problem. But I don't enough of this to help you out I'm afraid, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few months old but perhaps others ending up here from Google can use this advice.

You can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file. If this file does not exist, you can create it.

```
host yourpi.local
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rs
```

Where `yourpi.local` is the DNS name or IP address you've configured Deja Dup to use for backups and `id_rsa` is the name of your private key file.

This will fix your issue with Deja Dup and also remove the need to pass `-i` to your ssh command if that is currently how you invoke it.

Good luck!